# Spreadsheet data into email body - Python

Tags: excel, python-2.7, python-3.x, email, spreadsheet

Trying to mail a spreadsheet content as mail body.

Code sample:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import mimetypes
from email import encoders
from email.message import Message
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import csv
import os
import io
import codecs


fileMsg = MIMEBase("application","octet-stream")
with open('123.xls','r') as fp:
    contents = fp.read()
    fileMsg = MIMEText(contents)
outer.attach(fileMsg)
```

but getting an error msg:

```
contents = fp.read()
  File "\\ms\dist\python\PROJ\core\3.4.2-4-64\.exec\ia32.nt.4.0\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 756: character maps to <undefined>
```

Content i m trying to fetch is in tabular format like:
[image]

Body of the msg should be of as it is in the spread sheet..also need to fetch based on the sheet name...pls help..